# What quirks are there in making large strings with the || operator?

Tags: oracle, string-concatenation, number-formatting

Specifically, I am building out an email message body and getting some odd behavior with inserting CRLF (defined as `CRLF CONSTANT VARCHAR2(2) := CHR(13) || CHR(10);`) and with formatting dollar values (using this construct in two places with the same database field value and getting different results in the output `TRIM(TO_CHAR(foo.mydollars, '$99,999,999,990.00'))`).

In the CRLF case sometimes I get a newline and sometimes not.

In the number formatting I see:

```
1. $1,66942. 
2. $1,669.42
```

I am running Oracle 10g.

So I output the message body to the spool log file and dollar value formatting looks perfect there for all cases. Newlines are not an issue as it was the client messing with me. Still have the problem of dropping a decimal in the message by the time it lands in my inbox.

The program is passing the message body to the Oracle mail package through a wrapper that sets the character set to iso-8859-1 and the message body is processed like the following:

```
     UTL_SMTP.write_raw_data
      (c,
      UTL_ENCODE.quoted_printable_encode
        (UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw (   p_msgBody
          || UTL_TCP.crlf
          )
        )
     );
```

Answer (score 4):

My guess would be that it might be the email / mail reader that's causing the problem rather than Oracle.  Email clients do all sorts of funny formatting to the emails they receive.  Outlook in particular adds/remove line-breaks as it sees fit.

I suggest writing the email body into a temp/logging table so that you can compare that with the email?

Comment: Testing that approach now and will let you know.  Thanks.

Comment: So, the issue appears to be related to 76 character smtp line length limit in cases where the limit happens within the dollar value string section for six digit numbers only (i.e., in this case the decimal lands on the 76th column).  When I log to a text file the formatting is all fine. It's time to punt and just wrap the line on a word break so the problem goes away but any additional insights will be appreciated as it's always better to understand.